# Android sqlite selection

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a problem, I want to build selection in android that goes like

```
NOT LIKE List<String>
```

So that every String name from my list is excluded from query, currently I have it only for one name like

```
NOT LIKE NOT LIKE ('%' || ? || '%')
```

And I have no idea how to make it accept multiple names.

Answer (score 0):

The [IN operator](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#in_op) only does equality tests.

You have to write out multiple LIKEs, one for each pattern:

```
x NOT LIKE '%'||?||'%' AND x NOT LIKE '%'||?||'%' AND x NOT LIKE '%'||?||'%' ...
```

and use multiple parameters.